# Как изменять картинку?

Tags: javascript, html

Допустим есть два Input (Дата добавления и дата удаления) если была заполнена только Дата добавления то стоит картинка виде галочки, а если еще заполнена и Дата удаления то крестик. Как такую смену картинок реализовать на JavaScipt. Извиняюсь за то что не добавляю свой код (его просто нету, я не знаю как сделать).

Comment: ajax - function saccess - если не ошибаюсь

Answer (score 0):

Логика примерно такова:

```js
let input_value_dts = null;
let input_value_dte = null;
let curr_image = "";

if(!input_value_dts || !input_value_dte){
  console.log("Одна из дат не заполнена!");
  // тут метод смены картинки на крестик
  curr_image = "/bad.jpg"
} else {
  console.log("Обе даты присутствуют!");
  // а тут смены на галочку
  curr_image = "/good.jpg"
}
```